# Changing the href of an Area Id

Tags: jquery

I want to change the `href` of an area Id with code below.

```
<map name="green" id="green">
    <area manual_cm_sp="prospect-_-ZarzamoraUITT-_-iwant" href="http://es.t-mobile.com/shop/phones/?action=ADDPROMOTIONALPACKAGE&amp;id=5E725E06-32E7-430E-BA16-0327719DC724&amp;quantity=1" coords="380,419,746,442" alt="Llévate sólo el teléfono HTC Radar 4G" shape="RECT" title="Llévate sólo el teléfono HTC Radar 4G" id="prospectZarzamoraUITTiwant">
    <area manual_cm_sp="prospect-_-ZarzamoraUITT-_-iwant" href="http://es.t-mobile.com/shop/phones/?action=ADDPROMOTIONALPACKAGE&amp;id=7BFCC0F4-DF24-4137-85BE-F679A6F0372F&amp;quantity=1" coords="380,446,746,469" alt="Llévatelo con servicio internacional" shape="RECT" title="Llévatelo con servicio internacional" id="Area2">
</map>
```

Comment: And what's your problem? Getting a reference to the element? Accessing its `href` attribute? These are simple operations which should be covered by every jQuery tutorial. Have a look at the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and the [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. Reading documentation helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the id of the `area` you want to change:

```
$("#Area2").attr('href','newurl.php');
```

Comment: I want to know weathert i can use areaId like div id.

Comment: yes, you can. An area and a div are both elements in the DOM, and you can handle any DOM element ID the same in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID of an element you can select it and then use `.attr()` to access it's attributes:

```
$('#id-goes-here').attr('href', 'new-href-goes-here');
```

This can be done similarly in native JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('id-goes-here').href = 'new-href-goes-here';
```

I recommend checking-out the documentation for `.attr()`: http://api.jquery.com/attr (and hey, while you're there, why not browse around to see what you can learn)